# Password Generator choose what the password should include

Tags: javascript, html

I want to improve my Password Generator. I want that the user can choose what the password should include. For example you can choose that the password has letters but no numbers and characters. Can someone say me what i have to do?

here is my javascript and html:-

```js
  function randomPassword(length) {
    var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()-+<>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    var pass = " ";
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        pass += chars.charAt(i);
    }
    return pass;
}
function generate() {
    myform.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group " >
                <div class="col-sm-10">
    <br>
                    <input class="rowpassword" type="text" name="row_password" size="45s">
                    <br>
                     <input class="form-control passwordlength" type="text" name="length" value="8" > password length
                     <br>
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox"> Groß - und Kleinbuchstaben
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox"> numbers
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox"> specialcharacters
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" class="form-control button" value="Passwort generieren" onClick="generate();" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, check for the `checked` property for the checkboxs.
Then you can decide whether to have more than one pool of characters, or to apply filters which depend on what is checked. 
For the former, you can add the appropriate pools together, so something along the lines of

```
var chars ="";
var letterPool= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var specialPool="!@#$%^&*()-+<>"
var numberPool="1234567890"

if(characterType.checked)
{
    chars+=characterTypePool;
}
```

etc. 
If you do this, don't forget to have error handling for when none are selected.

UPDATE:
I've added a snippet (minus error handling) to demonstrate (don't forget to check the boxes!)

```js
 
function randomPassword(length) {
  var chars ="";
var letterPool= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var specialPool="!@#$%^&*()-+<>";
var numberPool="1234567890";

if(document.getElementById('letters').checked)
{
    chars+=letterPool;
}

if(document.getElementById('numbers').checked)
{
    chars+=numberPool;
}
  
if(document.getElementById('speChars').checked)
{
    chars+=specialPool;
}

    var pass = " ";
    for (var x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        pass += chars.charAt(i);
    }
    return pass;
}
function generate() {
    myform.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
}
```

```html
<form name="myform" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group " >
                <div class="col-sm-10">
    <br>
                    <input class="rowpassword" type="text" name="row_password" size="45s">
                    <br>
                     <input class="form-control passwordlength" type="text" name="length" value="8" > password length
                     <br>
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox" id='letters'> Groß - und Kleinbuchstaben
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox" id='numbers'> numbers
                     <br>
                     <input type="checkbox" id='speChars'> specialcharacters
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="button" class="form-control button" value="Passwort generieren" onClick="generate();" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

UPDATE TWO:

To guarantee that there will be at least one of each selected character type, you would need to add code. one way is to choose one at the start, and to add it to a random position in the final password. The following adaptation of the code does so by using an array and splice:

```
function randomPassword(length) {
  var chars ="";
var letterPool= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var specialPool="!@#$%^&*()-+<>";
var numberPool="1234567890";
var guaranteed="";

if(document.getElementById('letters').checked)
{
    chars+=letterPool;
    guaranteed+=letterPool.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letterPool.length));
}

if(document.getElementById('numbers').checked)
{
    chars+=numberPool;
  guaranteed+=numberPool.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * numberPool.length));
}

if(document.getElementById('speChars').checked)
{
    chars+=specialPool;
  guaranteed+=specialPool.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * specialPool.length));
}

    var pass =[];
    for (var x = 0,len=length-guaranteed.length; x < len; x++) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        pass.push(chars.charAt(i));
    }
  for(var x = 0,len=guaranteed.length; x < len; x++)
    pass.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * pass.length),0,guaranteed.charAt(x));
  pass=pass.join('');
    return pass;
}
function generate() {
    myform.row_password.value = randomPassword(myform.length.value);
}
```

Comment: first thanks for the fast answer. But now my code doesn't work.

Comment: @Leon I've added a fuller snippet, having added id's to get at the checkboxs more easily

Comment: @Leon , just to add, this does not guarantee a number will always be in if you select numbers; it just stops numbers from being included if you don't want them

Comment: and is there a way to to this?

Comment: @Leon lots of ways. one is to choose one of each required type at the beginning, then choose the rest of the characters, and then add at random.

Comment: @Leon I added one example of how you could do this